# Video upgrade problems (GT 710)

Tags: application-development

So I've been playing around with Ubuntu for a few months and finally decided to make my own NAS with it.  I've installed PLEX, OpenVPN and few other things using guides I've found on this site as well as others.

For some reason though, one of the easiest things to do in Windows is giving me a lot of trouble.  I bought a GeForce GT 710 and installed it.  The video is EXTREMELY laggy.  The input from keystrokes is more than 1 second (mouse movement seems fine which is weird).  So I read that I should use the proprietary drivers found in the "Additional Drivers" section however, when I did that my machine went to hell and wouldn't even load into Ubuntu.  I've spent all day recovering and am finally back to where I was pre-proprietary drivers.  Anyone have a better fix?  Is is better to install via command line for some reason?

Comment: What Brand/model system? I have a GT 720 and find open source nouveau & nVidia driver to be equivalent. And my cpu's internal graphics is about same performance, but I have a connector issue, so need 720 card for DVI output. Did you install more than one driver or incorrect one? You must purge old nVidia before installing a new one or you have conflicts. https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers Shows purge commands: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2362351&p=13649946#post13649946

Comment: I got a Zotac GT 710.  It cost like 30 bucks I think which is why I got it.  The mobo I have doesn't have an HDMI out and I was hoping to connect to my TV for PLEX, Kodi and use the PC as DVD player so I bought this cheap card just for HDMI.